# Using static page in Angular4 and using it as Index page

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

We have done creating single page app in Angular4 and then we got a need to have index page for welcome purpose having completely different in design, loading completely different css/js files, I googled it through and got this link to put is a direction:

[Serving static html outside Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519940/serving-static-html-outside-angular4)

But when I change the name of index.html to app.html and same in .angular-cli.json, I get this error:

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/src/index.html'
```