# Is it possible to call Static HTML Page in Angular project in Routing?

Tags: html, angular, routes

I have a few static pages like About US, Summary Info, etc. 
Now, I do not want to create these pages in Angular, because these pages may change in time. I want to reduce the overhead of building Angular project every time for a static page and I want to call this static HTML pages directly from my Angular page so that whenever any change in this static page occurs, I can just simply replace these pages. This way I won't need to re-build the entire Angular project. Is it possible???

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519940/serving-static-html-outside-angular4

Comment: Ohh yes thanks @Hunor. I got it now. Lets try this way and test it.

Comment: use content projection for this. have you page configurable based on the parameters you require and want to show.