# angular redirect to specific page if browser is unsupported

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I want to redirect to a static html page if the browser is unsupported for my application (basically IE up to 11).

This is my index.html start page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            if (IECheck() &&  && !window.location.href.includes('notsupported.html')) {          
               location.assign( window.location.href + 'assets/notsupported.html');
            }
        });

        function IECheck() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

            var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
            var ie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident');
            return msie > 0 || ie11 > 0;
        }

    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
    <base href="/">

    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />



</head>

<body>
    <div class="container body">
        <app-component>

        </app-component>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now it detects the browser version just fines. But instead of redirecting to the notsupported.html page, it loops infinitely, concatenating 'notsupported.html' to my root url in the address bar of the browser :
http://localhost:4200/notsupported.htm
htpp://localhost:4200/notsupported.htmnotsupported.htm
htpp://localhost:4200/notsupported.htmnotsupported.htmnotsupported.htm

and so on...

Could it be related to the usage of `ng serve` ? I haven't tried yet on my integration server. Or am I doing something wrong above ?

**EDIT**

Following recommendations below I moved the notsupported.html page to the asset folder. But the redirection is still not happening

Comment: location::assign will reload your app if the location target is not the current URL. So it will re-execute your code, doing again the **IECheck**,redirecting again, and so on.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So what's the correct approach to redirect to a static page in this given situation ?

Comment: Do you really need to have a static page ? You could use a Angular "NotSupportedComponent" bound to a "notsupported" route and do your IE checking on bootstrap of your app root component.

Comment: BTW, this would allow you to put the logic (which browser to include/exclude) in a dedicated service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add url check as well  something like

```
if (IECheck()  && !window.location.href.includes('notsupported.html')) {          
               location.assign( window.location.href + 'notsupported.html');
            }
```

Reason for infinte loop is even if loads notsupported page `DOMContentLoaded` will get fired and it 
will again check for `IECheck` and again append `notsupported.html` to url and same thing repeat again and again

Comment: I tried that. The URL changes to http://localhost:4200/notsupported.htm in the address bar (but the actual page is not loaded) and then reverts to http://localhost:4200. The redirection does not happen.

Comment: @Sam for that you will need to create root in angular or put your notsupported page to assets folder and load it like localhost:4200/assests/notsupported.htm

Comment: @Sam [refer to this so post related to loading static html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040550/5621827)

Comment: I moved the unsupported.html page in my asset folder, I added the path src/assets/unsupported.html to my assets structure in angular.json (although not needed since src/assets was already there) and I restarted ng serve. Same problem ! It still redirects indefinitely ....

Comment: @Sam did you update this condition `if (IECheck()  && !window.location.href.includes('notsupported.html'))` bcs without `&& !window.location.href.includes('notsupported.html')` it will not work and will keep looping again and again

Comment: I put the condition back again but same as before: it writes  localhost:4200/notsupported.htm to the address bar and then localhost:4200. But no redirection..

Comment: can you please update your question and i think you might forgot to update `location.assign( window.location.href + 'notsupported.html');` to `location.assign( window.location.href + 'assets\notsupported.html');`

Comment: Do you really need a html page ? why don't you just create a not-supported component and navigate to that from the script ???

Comment: @thisisyash that i have already suggested to OP in my first comment

Comment: @jitender I am saying to create a component instead of static html page

Comment: @jitender I have updated my post. @@thisisyash, well it is for old browsers so Angular will break from the start. A static page seems more appropriate I guess...

Comment: @thisisyash when i said ` create root in angular` actually i meant to say the same thing to create a component and then add root

Comment: @Sam you are still using the condition `if (IECheck())` instead of `if (IECheck() && !window.location.href.includes('notsupported.html'))`

Comment: @jitender, sorry my bad, I forgot to update the post (but my code is using the corrected condition)

Comment: @jitender It works !  I had a silly typo in my html page name. Sorry for the trouble. And many thanks